# Rails: External API Integration using RestClient (undefined local variable or method `username')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest-client

I am building a digital library, and I have completed a lot of the functionalities needed. I am currently having an issue with integrating the digital library with a Learning Management System (LMS).

I already have an admin authentication system for the digital library using the *Devise gem*. My goal is to allow users who want to access the digital library to login to the digital library using their Learning Management System (LMS) credentials (username and password).

I have been provided with the Login API endpoint and other needed parameters of the **Learning Management System (LMS)**, and I have created the **User Model**, the **Sessions Controller** and the **Sessions View Templates**.

I am currently using the **RestClient Gem** for the API call, but I having an error **undefined local variable or method `username' for # Did you mean? user_path**. I can't figure out where things went wrong.

**Sessions Controller**

```
require 'rest-client'

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    response = RestClient::Request.execute(
      method: :post,
      url: 'https://newapi.example.com/token',
      payload: { 'username': "#{username}",
                 'password':  "#{password}",
                 'grant_type':'password' },
      headers: { apiCode: '93de0db8-333b-4f478-aa92-2b43cdb7aa9f' }
    )

    case response.code
    when 400
      flash.now[:alert] = 'Email or password is invalid'
      render 'new'
    when 200
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Logged in!'
    else
      raise "Invalid response #{response.to_str} received."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Logged out!'
  end
end
```

**Sessions New View**

```
<p id=”alert”><%= alert %></p>
<h1>Login</h1>
<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :username %>
    <%= text_field_tag :username %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :password %>
    <%= password_field_tag :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag 'Login' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**User Model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password

  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

Any form of help with code samples will be greatly appreciated. I am also open to providing more information about this integration if required. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is in fact that inside your `SessionsController` in `create` action, you are interpolating `username` and `password`. There's no definition for these methods in your code so you get `undefined local variable or method`.

You could probably pick those from params like this:

```
def username
  params[:username]
end

def password
  params[:password]
end
```

Or interpolate them directly in payload replacing current method calls with `params[:username]` and `params[:password]`.

In such situations, it is good to use `byebug` or `pry` to debug your code and see what's happening inside your controller.

You could also think of closing some parts of your logic in Service objects - you shouldn't have more 10-15 lines in your controller action (unless the situation requires it)

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am having another issue **400 Bad Request**. Please here is a link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/57615476/10907864. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am having another issue **undefined local variable or method `user' for #SessionsController**. Please here is a link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/57615870/10907864. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use `params[:username]` rather than only `username` ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am having another issue **400 Bad Request**. Please here is a link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/57615476/10907864. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am having another issue **undefined local variable or method `user' for #SessionsController**. Please here is a link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/57615870/10907864. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`username` and `password` in payload are undefined variables. Please set their values. Possible values could be `params[:username]` and `params[:password]`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am having another issue **400 Bad Request**. Please here is a link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/57615476/10907864. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am having another issue **undefined local variable or method `user' for #SessionsController**. Please here is a link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/57615870/10907864. Thank you.