# Rails: External API Integration using RestClient (undefined local variable or method `user')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest-client

I am building a digital library, and I have completed a lot of the functionalities needed. I am currently having an issue with integrating the digital library with a Learning Management System (LMS).

I already have an admin authentication system for the digital library using the *Devise gem*. My goal is to allow users who want to access the digital library to login to the digital library using their Learning Management System (LMS) credentials (username and password).

I have been provided with the Login API endpoint and other needed parameters of the **Learning Management System (LMS)**, and I have created the **User Model**, the **Sessions Controller** and the **Sessions View Templates**.

I am currently using the **RestClient Gem** for the API call, and I just want to save the login information after succesful API call to the `session[:user_id] = user.id`, but I having an error **undefined local variable or method `user' for #SessionsController**. I can't figure out went wrong.

Below is my source code

**Sessions Controller**

```
require 'rest-client'

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    response = RestClient::Request.execute(
      method: :post,
      url: 'https://newapi.example.com/token',
      payload: { 'username': params[:username],
                 'password': params[:password],
                 'grant_type':'password' },
      headers: { apiCode: '93de0db8-333b-4f478-aa92-2b43cdb7aa9f' }
    )

    case response.code
    when 400
      flash.now[:alert] = 'Email or password is invalid'
      render 'new'
    when 200
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Logged in!'
    else
      raise "Invalid response #{response.to_str} received."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Logged out!'
  end
end
```

**Sessions New View**

```
<p id=”alert”><%= alert %></p>
<h1>Login</h1>
<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :username %>
    <%= text_field_tag :username %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :password %>
    <%= password_field_tag :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag 'Login' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**User Model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password

  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

Any form of help with code samples will be greatly appreciated. I am also open to providing more information about this integration if required. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unless there is more to your SessionsController, you do not, in fact, have a `user` method defined. Were you expecting it to be present from a gem like `devise`?

Comment: I was expecting it to be available from the `User` model. I just want to have a way of storing the login token to a session[:user_id] and then making user of it throughout a user's session.

Answer (score 0):

In your sessions controller, the line `session[:user_id] = user.id`, user is undefined i.e. You never assigned a value to the `user` variable.

Assuming your `User` database(in digital library, not LMS) have the record of user currently logging in, then you should use something like this:

```
when 200
  session[:user_id] = response.body.data.user.id
  redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Logged in!'
```

Now another case, When the user signs up in your LMS, then when he visits digital library app, and tries to login, he won't be able to. Because your digital library app doesn't have the user linked with LMS or knows anything about LMS. So, whenever user creates a session, you'll need to check if User record is present in your digital library DB or not, if not create one. You can do something like this:

```
when 200
  if User.find(response.body.data.user.id).present?
    session[:user_id] = response.body.data.user.id
    redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Logged in!'
  else
    user = User.create(id: response.body.data.user.id, username: response.body.data.user.username, passord: params[:password], password_confirmation: params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = response.body.data.user.id
    redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Logged in!'
  end
```

The above method is just for reference, you must add more validations if required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just tried the both solutions now but I am having another error **undefined method `data' for #<String:0x00007ffa98e52f00>**

Comment: The above code is just for reference. I'll update the answer if you post what is your `response` JSON from the LMS you receive. You'll need to parse the `user_id` from that JSON.

Comment: Thank you so much for this insight. i just removed `session[:user_id] = user.id` and  added `[:success, JSON.parse(response.to_str)]`  immediately after `when 200`

Comment: I also added `[:error, JSON.parse(response.to_str)]` immediately after `when 400`. The login works now, but when the **username** or **password** is not correct it still throws an error **400 Bad Request**. Do you have an idea how this can be fixed?

Comment: Where did you add `[:error, JSON.parse(response.to_str)]`? Can you show the whole `when 400` statement?

Comment: I added the `[:error, JSON.parse(response.to_str)]` immediately after `when 400`.  This is the whole case statement `case response.code
    when 200
      [:success, JSON.parse(response.to_str)]
      redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Logged in!'
    when 400
      [:error, JSON.parse(response.to_str)]
      flash.now[:alert] = 'Email or password is invalid'
      render 'new'
    else
      raise "Invalid response #{response.to_str} received."
    end`

Comment: Ohh, in rails there is no `error` status. Try using `:bad_request` or `:unauthorized` or `:unprocessable_entity`. Example: `[:bad_request, JSON.parse(response.to_str)]` or `[:unprocessable_entity, JSON.parse(response.to_str)]`

Comment: I am still facing the same issue of **400 bad request** whenever the username or password is incorrect. I am of the opinion that I should change the code from **400** to another code. Do you have a different thought?

Comment: Maybe I should edit your answer to reflect the changes that we made, so that I can mark it as correct since it is relative to this question.

Comment: I have asked the question about **404 bad request** here https://stackoverflow.com/q/57621030/10907864, please help me out if you can.

Comment: Can you tell me why you're adding this array `[:bad_request, JSON.parse(response.to_str)]`? or this one `[:success, JSON.parse(response.to_str)]`.

Comment: I added them as responses for the api request for **successful** and **unsuccessful** requests. I observed that the request was failing with the arrays.

Comment: I just checked ur new question, Your code is working because you have removed `session[:user_id]` line, so it just redirect's with flash message. User is still not authenticated in digital library app. Also the `[:success, JSON.parse(response.to_str)]` is useless and it's just an array and rails will ignore it.

Comment: The ans is simple but looks little complicated, can we collab on this issue? Is it a open-source project?

Comment: That's so true, the **arrays** are useless. It is not an open-source project, but we can collaborate on it. How would you like us to collaborate on this? Zoom or what do you think? Thank you so much for your concern. Hoping to hear from you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198361/discussion-between-allenbrkn-and-promise-preston).

Comment: I am available on chat now, please check the chat group

Comment: I'm available now! Thanks for posting it here.