# Rails: External API Integration using RestClient (400 Bad Request) response code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest-client

I am building a digital library, and I have completed a lot of the functionalities needed. I am currently having an issue with integrating the digital library with a Learning Management System (LMS).

I already have an admin authentication system for the digital library using the *Devise gem*. My goal is to allow users who want to access the digital library to login to the digital library using their Learning Management System (LMS) credentials (username and password).

I have been provided with the Login API endpoint and other needed parameters of the **Learning Management System (LMS)**, and I have created the **User Model**, the **Sessions Controller** and the **Sessions View Templates**.

I am currently using the **RestClient Gem** for the API call, but I having an error **400 Bad Request**. The login works (when 200), but when the username or password is not correct (when 422) it will throw an error 400 Bad Request. I have tried to debug the issue but no success yet.

Below is my source code

**Sessions Controller**

```
require 'rest-client'

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    response = RestClient::Request.execute(
      method: :post,
      url: 'https://newapi.example.com/token',
      payload: { 'username': params[:username],
                 'password': params[:password],
                 'grant_type':'password' },
      headers: { apiCode: '93de0db8-333b-4f478-aa92-2b43cdb7aa9f' }
    )

    case response.code
    when 200
      [:success, JSON.parse(response.to_str)]
      redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Logged in!'
    when 422
      [:unprocessable_entity, JSON.parse(response.to_str)]
      flash.now[:alert] = 'Email or password is invalid'
      render 'new'
    else
      raise "Invalid response #{response.to_str} received."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Logged out!'
  end
end
```

**Sessions New View**

```
<p id=”alert”><%= alert %></p>
<h1>Login</h1>
<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :username %>
    <%= text_field_tag :username %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :password %>
    <%= password_field_tag :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag 'Login' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**User Model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password

  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

Any form of help with code samples will be greatly appreciated. I am also open to providing more information about this integration if required. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the 400 returned by the LMS api or does your application throw a 400 when the LMS api returns a 422?

Comment: Oh, the error is thrown by the digital library application, not the LMS.